# Backbone view-property: one on instance, one on prototype?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, backbone.js, prototype

Yeah, that title doesn't make much sense.

I have a view. This view creates sub-views. These subviews are stores in an array so that I can remove them at some point.

```
MN.ContactsView = MN.BaseView.extend ({

tagName : "div",

contactViewItems : [],

initialize : function(){        
    this.listenTo(MN.client.contacts, "add", this.addOne);
    this.listenTo(MN.client.contacts, "reset", this.addAll);
    this.listenTo(MN.client.contacts, "all", this.render);      
    MN.client.contacts.fetch();

},  render: function(){

},

addOne : function($contactModel){       
    var view = new MN.ContactsViewItem({model: $contactModel});
    this.contactViewItems.push(view);
    $("#contactsContainer").append(view.render().el);

},

addAll : function(){
    MN.client.contacts.each(this.addOne, this)
},

close : function(){

},

destroy: function(){
    for(var i =0; i < this.contactViewItems.length; i++) this.contactViewItems[i].destroy();
    this.contactViewItems = [];
    debugger;
    console.log("Length: " + this.contactViewItems.length );
    MN.BaseView.prototype.destroy.call(this);   
},
```

when I destroy the view and check the debugger, I see the same variable 2 times. What is up backbone?

[image: enter awesome image description here, dawg]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're creating your class by using the `extend` method, the properties you gave will be put in the prototype. That means, they'll be shared by all the instances of your class. If you happen to change the value of that property in some instance, you will **shadow** the prototype so that this property has a new value, not linked with the prototype anymore.

So, here's what's happening here:

When you modify `contactViewItems` with `this.contactViewItems.push(view);`, you don't change the value stored in the prototype. Rather, you change the object pointed by the value. So you're still modifying an array, shared by all the instances of your class.

However, when you do `this.contactViewItems = [];`, you really are changing the value, as you're giving it a totally new object. At that moment, you simply **shadow** the prototype of your class for this instance in particular. The prototype is of course still there (you didn't do anything to it), therefore you see the property twice.

Now, it's certainly not working as you want it to work, and there are several solutions that I'm sure you can think of now that you know the core of the problem (I don't know the details of your app, so I can't be of much help without further details).

Answer (score 0):

> when I destroy the view and check the debugger, I see the same variable 2 times.

Because you've created it a second time on the instance in the `destroy` function:

```
this.contactViewItems = [];
```

If you wanted to clear the array on your prototype, you should've used either

```
MN.ContactsView.prototype.contactViewItems = [];
```

or

```
this.contactViewItems.length = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

As Loamhoof pointed out, the issue is your contactViewItems are attributes of your ContactsViews prototype.

A simply way to modify your view so that it behaves the way you are probably expecting, is to NOT iniitilize contactViewItems with an empty array. Instead, create the empty array in your initialize.

For example:

```
MN.ContactsView = MN.BaseView.extend ({

tagName : "div",

contactViewItems : null,

initialize : function(){        
    this.contactViewItems = [];
    this.listenTo(MN.client.contacts, "add", this.addOne);
    this.listenTo(MN.client.contacts, "reset", this.addAll);
    this.listenTo(MN.client.contacts, "all", this.render);      
    MN.client.contacts.fetch();
},
```

Now, adding items to this.contactViewItems is directly on the view object (what you probably want in this case) while the prototype contains a contactViewItems that is null.